# Set Value of form input from variable in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a variable named colWidth in jquery which runs some math on numbers grabbed from an input using jquery. How do I set a value of an input field with an id of #test to the value of colWidth?

```
$("input#width").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("span#width-text").text(value);
}).keyup();

$("input#columns").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("span#columns-text").text(value);
}).keyup();

$("input#gutter").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("span#gutter-text").text(value);
}).keyup();

$("input#gutter").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("span#gutter-text").text(value);
}).keyup();

$(function(){
    $('a#calc').click(function(){
        var width = $('input#width').val();
        var col = $('input#columns').val();
        var gutter = $('input#gutter').val();
        var newWidth = width / col;
        var colSize = (gutter + gutter) * col;
        var colWidth = newWidth - colSize;
        $('input#test').val(colWidth);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Louis - Has your issue been resolved? You accepted an answer that appears to be identical to the code in your question.

Comment: Well, I guess he just validated what I needed to do to "push" the data to the input field #test. 

However, in said input field I am getting "NaN" that is showing up. I presume I am not grabbing the data right, or really there is no data being pulled in which I thought I was doing with 
"var width = $('input#width').val();" and         
"var col = $('input#columns').val();" and doing my calculation by 
"var newWidth = width / col;"....

Comment: Yes, if any of those values are `undefined` or are not a number, you'll get a result of `NaN` which means Not a Number. You should `console.log()` or `alert()` each of your variables to see if it is the value you expect. Also, be aware that `.val()` returns a String. Some math operators will accept a String, and convert it for you, but the `+` operator will concatenate the string. So if `gutter` is `10`, then `gutter + gutter` will be `1010`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Louis,

You're getting `NaN` because your calculation is running before the user has a chance to enter any numbers into the `<input>` elements.

In your question, you use a `.click()` handler to fire the calculation, but on your page, you don't. It just runs when the page loads.

Therefore the result of `.parseInt()` is `NaN`, and the result of the calculations are the same.

Comment: Oh. Ok. (I do apologize, I am still trying to learn the in/outs of jquery).. If I may ask, in your opinion, how do I rectify this?

Comment: @Louis - You need to trigger the calculation *after* the user has given some input into the fields. In your question, you used a `.click()` event on an `<a>` element. That would work just fine. Just provide `<a id="calc">calculate</a>` in your HTML, and put your calculation in the handler like you did above.

Comment: dw, thanks.. It basically was staring me in the face *palm to forehead*

Answer (score 4):

`$("#test").val(colWidth)`

Comment: Am I doing something wrong in my above code while trying to get the data? I now recieve a NaN in the #test input field.

Comment: Topera - This wouldn't give any different result from the code in the question `$("input#test").val(colWidth)`

Comment: @patrick - When I answer the question, the question didn't have the code. :)

Comment: Topera - Ah, I see. Didn't realize that. Sorry about that. :o)